Django system Not Logging User Out on Browser/Tab Close (Chrome/Safari)
Regular Safari/Chrome: Sessions don't expire on tab or browser close.
#middleware.py

if manager:
    if client.logout_browser_close_manager:
        request.session.set_expiry(0)
        request.session.modified = True


#settings.py

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True


I can confirm the following:

The middleware.py is added to the middleware configuration in settings.py

The session cookie shows session instead of a date with the following code above, but does not log the user out.

Tried with redis, adding the following - SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache', along with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

cleaned up the db, using delete FROM django_session, have ran a migrate after it

I have deleted all cookies within the browsers

Turned off and tested with cross-site tracking settings with safari

Django version - 3.2.24



"Chrome Incognito: Sessions don't expire" are you sure?? How would the session not expire if you close the browser given you were using Incognito mode? The browser surely won't save any cookies, etc. so I don't think this is as you say.

Yeah, my bad this is not the case. Please ignore that point.
